# Windows Community Toolkit --> TokenizingTextBox dynamic change of SuggestedItemsSource

Tags: c#, winui-3, windows-community-toolkit

is it possible to change the **SuggestedItemsSource** in a **TokenizingTextBox** **dynamically**?

Currently my list consists of all entries, but as soon as the user starts typing, the suggestions should only match the input.

I tried it like that:

**XAML**

```
                            <controls:TokenizingTextBox Header="Model"
                                                        PlaceholderText="Type a model name"
                                                        Margin="0,24,0,0"
                                                        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                                                        TextMemberPath="Text"
                                                        TokenDelimiter=","
                                                        SuggestedItemsSource="{Binding SuggestionList, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                                        TokenItemAdded="TokenizingTextBox_TokenItemAdded"
                                                        TextChanged="TokenizingTextBox_TextChanged"/>
```

**Code behind**

```
        private void TokenizingTextBox_TextChanged(AutoSuggestBox sender, AutoSuggestBoxTextChangedEventArgs args)
        {
            ((ViewModels.FolderName.ViewModel)DataContext).searchName(sender.Text);
        }
```

**ViewModel**

```
      private List<string> _suggestionList = new List<string>();
      public List<string> SuggestionList
      {
          get => _suggestionList ;
          set => SetProperty(ref _suggestionList , value);
      }


     internal void searchName(string searchString )
     {
         SuggestionList.Clear();
         for (int i = 0; i < originalData.Count; i++)
         {
             if (originalData[i].Name.IndexOf(searchString, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0)
             {
                 SuggestionList.Add(originalData[i]);
             }

         }
     }
```

But when typing letters, the program crashes without usable exception. Is it not possible or what I am doing wrong?

I hope someone can help me or give me a good hint :)

**What I know**

- The crash is due to: SuggestionList.Clear()

But if remove the clear part, the suggestion list is also not updated dynamic? Here my expectation would be that the SuggestionList gets bigger and bigger, because duplicate entries should be present.

**My expactation is:**

- Dynamic change of SuggestedItemsSource, so that the user will only see suggestions matches with his  typed letters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work:

**TokenizingTextBoxEx.cs**

```cs
using CommunityToolkit.WinUI;
using CommunityToolkit.WinUI.Controls;
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml;
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Linq;

namespace TokenizingTextBoxExample;

public class TokenizingTextBoxEx : TokenizingTextBox
{
    public TokenizingTextBoxEx()
    {
        this.Loaded += TokenizingTextBoxEx_Loaded;
    }

    private void TokenizingTextBoxEx_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.FindDescendant<AutoSuggestBox>() is AutoSuggestBox autoSuggestBox)
        {
            autoSuggestBox.TextChanged -= AutoSuggestBox_TextChanged;
            autoSuggestBox.TextChanged += AutoSuggestBox_TextChanged;
        }
    }

    // This is based on the WinUI 3 Gallery AutoSuggestBox sample code.
    private void AutoSuggestBox_TextChanged(AutoSuggestBox sender, AutoSuggestBoxTextChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        if (args.Reason is AutoSuggestionBoxTextChangeReason.UserInput &&
            this.SuggestedItemsSource is IEnumerable<string> suggestedItems)
        {
            List<string> suitableItems = new();
            string[] splitText = sender.Text.ToLower().Split(" ");

            foreach (string item in suggestedItems)
            {
                bool found = splitText.All((key) =>
                {
                    return item.ToLower().Contains(key);
                });

                if (found)
                {
                    suitableItems.Add(item);
                }
            }

            if (suitableItems.Count == 0)
            {
                suitableItems.Add("No results found");
            }

            sender.ItemsSource = suitableItems;
        }
    }
}
```

**NOTE:**

`FindDescendant` comes from the [CommunityToolkit.WinUI.Extensions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/extensions/frameworkelementextensions) NuGet package.

Comment: It works on my side. My first guess is that you are also subscribing to `TokenizingTextBox`'s `TextChanged` event. Can you debug it and make sure that you're actually subscribing to the `AutoSuggestTextBox`?

Comment: With FindDescendant I only find the first element....but i have multipe boxes. How can I map the event  to a specific TokenizingTextBox

Comment: You need to call `FindDescendant` from the `TokenizingTextBox's`'s `Loaded` event just like in my sample code.

Comment: Thats the point. I did it...but the AutoSuggestBox_TextChanged event is only fired by my first TokenizingTextBox no other one. The Loaded_Event is fired by my third TokenizingTextBox

Comment: It seems like you are trying to subscribe to those events from the outside of the `TokenizingTextBoxEx` control. The code in my answer is for a custom control class. You should start trying to use the entire class, and not only parts of it.

Comment: Can you provide the github link of this control? I dont find it.

Comment: This is not in GitHub. You can just create a class file **TokenizingTextBoxEx.cs** and paste the code.

Comment: If this answer solves your problem, please accept it as the answer so we can close this session.